# How to reduce amplification of solar inverter relay due to drywall?

Tags: sound-proofing

I have recently had solar panels installed on the roof of our attic. They hung the inverter on a hollow plasterboard wall as this was the most easily accessible.

However, every time the solar inverter turns on, there is a rather annoying series of clicks of an internal relay, and the sound is massively amplified due to the hollow wall onto which it is mounted. I now have two options,

- Hang the inverter on an outer (stone) wall nearby. Since I don't want to void my warranty right away (or worse, create a fire risk with diy DC cabling), this probably involves getting the contractor over, and the inverter would have to hang over the stairs making it quite inaccessible.
- Somehow reduce the emission of sound from the drywall.

What options do I have for the second option? I suppose I can put some damping material between the inverter and the wall. My instinct would be to drill the screw through felt patches, but maybe there are better options? Also, the sound might still transfer through the screws into the wall. Perhaps there exist purpose-built wall plug / anchors with sound or vibration isolation?

Comment: Can you add a photo of how it's mounted to the wall?

Comment: @Huesmann See page 34 of this manual: https://www.solaredge.com/sites/default/files/se_hd_wave_inverter_with_SetApp_installation_guide_na.pdf So a mounting bracket with 3 screws in the wall on which the inverter is hung (so at the bottom it rests with the heatsink on the wall - we do not have the DC safety switch box which I guess is not required in our locale)

Comment: Well, you want to decouple the inverter from the wall as much as you can.  The easy button is to start with slipping something like a towel at the bottom btwn the inverter and wall.  This won't decouple the bracket from the wall, but it's a start, and basically "free."

Answer (score 1):

Look around your home store for some rubber grommets and put them on the inverter then put the mounting screws through them.[image]

Comment: That could work, but it'd depend on how the inverter is fastened to the wall.

Comment: There are many different types of rubber isolators I would try gromets Most inverters are screwed in even a large gromet on the back and front with a washer under the screw head helps dampen the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 sunny boy inverters and they are outside. I know the clicking you are talking about, but I dont have to live with it as my inverters are outside. What if you told the installer about the noise and requested that they put them outside. It wont cost you anything to ask.